# Registered Autofac type as single instance but instantiating new instance per API call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, singleton, autofac

Using ASP.NET API with Autofac, trying to register a single instance in web api

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>().SingleInstance();
```

Note, above mentioned SomeService depends on SomeRepository that is injected and configured using

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<SomeRepository>().As<ISomeRepository>();
```

Injected using

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
    {
        private readonly ISomeRepository someRepository;

        public AppSettingService(ISomeRepository someRepository)
        {
            this.someRepository= someRepository;
        }
        ...
```

I expect this to instantiate only once throughout application life, but new instance is created per API call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you double checked that the registration for `SomeService` is not being overriden when wiring up the container?

Comment: Is `SomeRepository` injected into other classes perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SomeRepository was not registered as a single instance. Register SomeRepository as a single instance.